# NodeJS - Upload using Multer with a Promise

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, promise, multer

I've been rewriting my very simple server lately. I have been introducing promises and the final part of my rewrite is implementing my post methods which involves using Multer for uploading images.
This is what I have so far. The GET works perfect, as does the POST when I remove the image upload part of it.
Unfortunately when I introduce Multer I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
&nbsp; &nbsp;at exports.format (util.js:91:18)
&nbsp; &nbsp;at Console.log (console.js:46:37)
&nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.createACategory (/root/api/controllers/controller.js:34:18)
```

Here is my Route class where I am calling the POST:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app, gameCategoryList) {
  var multer = require('multer');

  var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, '/var/www/html/uploadsCategoryIcon');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
      var originalname = file.originalname;
      var extension = originalname.split(".");
      callback(null, extension[0] + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + extension[extension.length-1]);
    }
  });

  var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

  app.get('/api/gameCategories', (req, res) => {
    gameCategoryList.listAllCategories().then(category => res.json(category));
  });

  app.post('/api/createGameCategory', upload.single('gameCategoryImage'), (req, res) => {
    gameCategoryList.createACategory(req.body, req.file).then(category => res.json(category));
  });

};
```

This is what the method looks like in my controller class:

```
createACategory(body, file) {
         var splitPath = file.path.split("html");
         var imagePath = 'example.com' + splitPath[1];

         var new_category = new Category({
           categoryName: body.categoryName,
           categoryTag: body.categoryTag,
           categoryImageUrl: imagePath
         });

         return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

           new_category.save(function(err, category) {
             if (err) {
               return reject(err)
             } else {
               return resolve(category)
             }
           });

          }).then((category) => {

            if(category)
            {
              return category
            }
            else
            {
              return { success: false }
            }
          });
       }
```

UPDATE:

On line 34 of controller.js is:

```
var new_category = new Category({
   categoryName: body.categoryName,
   categoryTag: body.categoryTag,
   categoryImageUrl: imagePath
});
```

When I remove the image part of this code (categoryImageUrl: imagePath) and don't pass any file or image, this code works fine.

Comment: Provide more bug log information like `error stack trace`...

Comment: I have updated my question to include the full error received

Comment: Show me what is on `controllers/controller.js` at line 34

Comment: As your description, I think the issue come from a `console.log` line, when you try to print out a object to log with syntax like `console.log("My object" + object);`, js will try to cast object to string, but it throw a error as what you get back.